# How to create a class which uses member functions defined in another class C++

Tags: c++, class, inheritance, member-functions

I'm new to object oriented programming and am struggling a bit with how best to write classes.

I am trying to abstract the idea of sorting to objects that are not just lists of numbers. I have an abstract base class, `SortableContainer`, which contains all the necessary virtual functions for comparing and swapping elements, along with some overloaded operators. I then have two classes derived from that, `MVector` and `CoordinateArray`. Both of these derived classes have proper definitions for all the virtual functions in the base class. Everything up to this point has worked just fine. `MVector` just stores vector-like objects and `CoordinateArray` stores vectors of coordinates onto which a notion of 'less than' has been defined.

My problem now is that I have created a new class, `Life`, which I want to use to implement the game of life using a `CoordinateArray` object to store the alive cells. The outline of my `Life` class looks like this:

```
class Life
{
public:
   CoordinateArray LiveCells;

   Life();
};
```

When I create a Life object and initialise it with the coordinates of some alive cells, none of the member functions defined in the `CoordinateArray` derived class will work. How can I fix this? Do I have to derive the `Life` class from the `SortableContainer` class and then override all the pure virtual functions? Any help or direction to help will be much appreciated.

Comment: Please have a look at this [C++ books](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) list.

Comment: Why do you have all these classes? They seem completely unnecessary for the problem at hand. (And for the vast majority of problems, for that matter.)

Comment: Why do you say that "none of the fuctions ... will work"? I don't get you point. Could you give an example?

Comment: What exactly happens that's not expected? What exact does not happen that is expected? "will not work" is not a problem description, much less a question.

Comment: Does your CoordinateArray class have a public interface? A class outside of the inheritance hierarchy can only use public functions of the class.

Comment: It would be great to see what your `CoordinateArray` class looks like, as well as examples of what you are trying to do with `Life` and what is going wrong. If you're expecting a `Life` object to have member functions from `CoordinateArray`, then it needs to inherit from `CoordinateArray`; if you just want the `CoordinateArray` object *in* `Life` to use those functions, then you just need to make sure they were declared public.

Comment: @molbdnilo The other classes were made as part of a larger project - I then have to use the sorting functions as a way to implement the game of life

Comment: @Arkadiy apologies for not being clear - One example of something that won't work is that I have overloaded the << operator in my `CoordinateArray` class, but when I instantiate a `Life` object and try to print it, it tells me "no operator "<<" matches these operands". Similar errors occur when I try to access the size of a `Life` object. Thanks for your reply

Comment: @Basya from all the responses I am guessing this is where the issue lies - my functions have all been written under a public interface but I perhaps have made a slip somewhere with the syntax

Comment: @colopop Thanks for your reply, I wasn't sure about putting too much code in my question but I shall outline my `CoordinateArray` class:

Comment: @colopop 

    class CoordinateArray : public SortableContainer
{
public:
 // constructors
 CoordinateArray() {}
 explicit CoordinateArray(int n) : v(n) {} // creates a square 
        coordinate array of length root n

 // access element (lvalue)
 IntegerCoordinate &operator[](unsigned int index)
 {
  assert(index < v.size());
  return v[index];
 }

There are then several other member functions (under public:) which include functions for swapping elements, etc. It ends with `private: std::vector<IntegerCoordinate> v;` where I have also defined an `IntegerCoordinate` struct

Comment: Please edit the updates into your questions. Code is not easy to look at in the comments. Also, please clarify what you mean by "try to access the size of a Life object" - do you mean `sizeof`?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question simply and in a pragmatical way, yes, if you want your `Life` object to have some member functions they need to come from somewhere, the most straight forward way is to derive it from a class containing those member functions, composition does not transfer members to the owner, inheritance does that:

```
class Life : public CoordinateArray
{
public:
   Life();
};
```

Now you can use your `Life objects` as a `CoordinateArray` object. If anything is pure virtual in the parent class you will indeed need to implement it in the derived class, but even if something is not you can still reimplement it in the child class to overwrite the parent behaviour.

I avoided conception and design problematics on purpose, this is mainly a technical answer, judging this from a design point of view requires more context and has some subjective side too so that's another story altogether.

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful to see the declaration of CoordinateArray. However, I suspect you need to make public methods in CoordinateArray. If the methods are declared private (i.e., they come after `private:` in your class declaration), then they can only be used inside the class's own scope. If they're declared public (underneath `public:`), then they can be used in any scope. (As a sidenote, there is one other classification, protected, which means they can be used by the class and any of its subclasses.)

Answer (score -1):

In order to initialize co-ordinates of some live cells declare the class CoordinateArray LiveCells public to Life

```
class Life::public CoordinateArray{ }
```